# Fwrite a dynamic structure passed by reference

Tags: c

Not sure if my title makes much sense, but what I am trying to do is fwrite from dynamic structure to file, but what makes this somewhat harder is that my structure is passed by reference and I do not know how 1st parameter of fwrite should look like. Here is a part of the code:

```
void editData(FILE* fPtr, Car* carPtr[], int* size)
{
int number = 0;
printData(carPtr, size);

while(1)
{
    if ((scanf("%d", &number) == 1) && (getchar() == '\n'))
    {
        if ((number > 0) && (number <= *size))
        {
            char make[15] = "", model[15] = "";
            int year = 0;
            double price = 0;

            if (getUserInput(make, model, &year, &price) == 1)
            {
                strcpy((*carPtr+number-1)->make, make);
                strcpy((*carPtr+number-1)->model, model);
                (*carPtr+number-1)->year = year;
                (*carPtr+number-1)->price = price;

                fseek(fPtr, sizeof(Car) * number-1, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(**&carPtr[number-1]**, sizeof(Car), 1, fPtr);
            }
```

And that is how I call this function from main:

```
FILE* db = NULL;
int choice = 0;
db = openDatabase(db);

Car* cr = NULL;
int size = 0;
loadData(db, &cr, &size);
while((choice = menuChoice()) != 5)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                insertData(db, &cr, &size);
                break;
            case 2:
                **editData(db, &cr, &size);**
                break;
            case 4:
                printData(&cr, &size);
                break;
        }
    }
    free(cr);
    fclose(db);
}
```

Memory allocation to the structure happens in a different function.

If structure was local, in fwrite as 1st parameter I would write

```
&carPtr[number-1]
```

But in my case this does not work.

Car declaration:

```
struct car
{
    char make[15];
    char model[15];
    int year;
    double price;
};
```

Comment: How is `Car` declared?

Comment: Edited my question to include it

Comment: I think you're messing up things. What you call "passing parameters for reference", inexistent concept in C,  is used in `loadData()` only because there the memory is allocated and the data retrieved from database and load in it, passing the address of the pointer allows to set its value. In the other functions you must simply pass the pointer `cr` and use use it to pint to the data.

Comment: I think I tried passing cr before, but then the structure got changed only locally, outside of the function it did not.

Comment: To elaborate on @Frankie_C s comment: C does not support references, it is strictly pass-by-value. A pointer is a first class type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Car *pnt
```

this is a pointer to `Car`.

The expression `*(...)` dereferences the `...` into an object.

The expression `a[b]` is equal to `*(a + b)`.

```
Car* carPtr[]
```

in a function parameter list (ie. in `function(... Car *carPtr[] ....)` is equal to:

```
Car **carPtr
```

This is a pointer to a pointer to Car.

```
&carPtr[x]
```

is equal to:

```
carPtr + x
```

which is not what you want. You have a pointer to an array of cars, not an array of pointers to cars. You want first to derefernce carPtr, then increment. You want:

```
&(*carPtr)[x]
```

which is equal to:

```
((*carPtr) + x)
```

So try:

```
fwrite(&(*carPtr)[number-1], sizeof(Car), 1, fPtr);
```

Also I would rewrite the

```
(*carPtr+number-1)->
```

into

```
(*carPtr)[number - 1].
```

as to indicate that you are handling a pointer to an array.

But really, I would rewrite the api to handle better abstraction:

```
struct cars_s {
     Car *cars;
     size_t carslen;
};

int main() {
    struct cars_s cars;

    insertData(db, &cars);
     ...
    editData(db, &cars);
}
```

which will make you code more readable, when you do `editData(FILE *db, struct cars_s *cars)` and `cars->cars[x].year = year` instead of `Cars *cars[], int *size` and `(*carPtr)[x].year = year`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It compiles, but I have same problem as with the answer above, file gets filled with random values.

Comment: Do you `memset(cars, 0, sizeof(Car))` or call `calloc` on allocation? If not, there will be random values after the null terminator in string.

Comment: Tried using memset on allocation, but unless I have used it wrong, it did not help. I do not think that structure is bad, as I printf it to check and it looks the way it should be. I think it fails at fwrite step.

Comment: Then, create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I can copy&paste in to my [editor](https://www.onlinegdb.com/). Without a minimal example, it's just guesses.

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite` expects a pointer to a byte buffer to write.

If you have a local variable (including structure), you would need to get its address with the & operator, like this:

```
Car myCar;
fwrite(&myCar, sizeof(Car), 1, fout);
```

But, if you already have a pointer, then you don't need the & opertator:

```
Car *myCar;
fwrite(myCar, sizeof(Car), 1, fout);
```

Same thing goes if you have an array of pointers to structures:

```
Car* cars[];
fwrite(cars[i], sizeof(Car), 1, fout);
```

Since `cars[i]` already has the address `fwrite` needs, there is no need for any operators.

One thing to note is that C compilers pad structures - they may insert unused bytes between fields to make sure each field starts on a boundary (depends on your system word alignment, usually 4).

So, those 15 `char` arrays may have an extra byte appended to round to 16.
If you write the whole structure to file, those bytes will also be written.

This is why it is usually recommended to write each field separately, but if this is just an exercise, it may not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work yet. Program compiles successfully, but fwrite writes something random, not what I want to write. Structure itself seems to be good, as I print entire structure to check.

Comment: How are you looking at the file? Are you using a hex editor? Windows Notepad?

Comment: Another function freads file to a structure which i print afterwards.

Comment: Is it possible the read function is incorrect? Try looking at the file with hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not fwrite, but fseek after all.
This:

```
fseek(fPtr, sizeof(Car) * number-1, SEEK_SET);
```

must be changed to this:

```
fseek(fPtr, sizeof(Car) * (number-1), SEEK_SET);
```

I've managed to omit parenthesis and because of this fwrite would write to wrong place. Fread would then read more than there is memory allocated and thats why I think random things happened.

As for correct way to write fwrite:

```
fwrite(&(*carPtr)[number-1], sizeof(Car), 1, fPtr);
```

This works perfectly